# Error al ejecutar el código, no guarda la información en cache TypeError: Failed to execute 'addAll' on 'Cache': Request failed

Tags: javascript, cache

Hola a todos estoy tratando de cachear un sitio web pero se me presenta el siguiente error TypeError: Failed to execute 'addAll' on 'Cache': Request failed al principio pensé que era un error en el orden de los archivos o de ruta así que los acomode pero no sigue apareciendo, agradezco de antemano el apoyo que me puedan brindar, acá dejo les dejo el código:

```
 let version = "version 1";   
 const archivos = ['./index.html',
                './nosotros.html',
                './colecciones.html',
                './blog.html',
                './contacto.html',
                './15años.html',
                './casualf.html',
                './fantasias.html',
                './galas.html',
                './novias.html',
                './vniñas.html',
                './css/estilos.css',
                './css/estilos2.css',
                './css/estilos3.css',
                './css/estilos4.css',
                './css/estilos5.css',
                './css/estilos6.css',
                './css/navbar.css',
                './js/codigo.js',
    ];

 self.addEventListener("install", e => {
        console.log("Instalando Service Worker");
        e.waitUntil(
            caches.open(version).then(cache =>{
            return cache.addAll(archivos).then(res =>{
                console.log("Informacion Cacheada con Exito");
            }).catch(e =>{
                console.log(e);
            })
        })
    )   
})
```

Answer (score 0):

hola deberías de checar si tus archivos existen en la dirección marcada

hice una prueba con tu mismo código y los archivos los carga de forma correcta

```
<script>
 const archivos = ['./',
            './blog.php',
            './conocenos.php',
            './contacto.php',
            './index.php',
            './productos.php',];

  let version = "version 1"; 
  caches.open(version).then(cache =>{
        return cache.addAll(archivos).then(res =>{
            console.log("Informacion Cacheada con Exito");
        }).catch(e =>{
            console.log(e);
        })
      })
```

[image: imagen de mensaje de consola]

otra opción de saber si se cargan los archivos de forma correcta es si vas a la pestaña de red de tus herramientas de desarrollador del navegador podrás ver si se cargan los archivos como puedes ver al no existir uno se cancelan todos y manda el error que mencionas
[image: muestra de error]

Comment: Muchas gracias por el apoyo, revise lo que me indicaste de la red y allí estaba el error porque la rutas de los archivos no era correctas, es decir los html y css no estaban en la misma ruta por ello se cancelaban, mil gracias nuevamente ahora si funciona perfecto.